# android - adding a slider-to-unlock view to a listview

Tags: android, listview, drag, slide

i'm trying to put a sliding view (similar to the "slide-to-unlock" on locker screens) into all of a listView's items . 
however , even though it worked fine on its own , i get 2 problems:

1.sometimes, the entire row is becoming black . i thought it was a selection issue , so i used:
    this.setSelector(color.transparent);
for the listView itself, but it didn't help fixing it.

2.when dragging the view outside of the item (which contains it) , i can't capture any more touch events besides "ACTION_CANCEL" , so the only thing i can do is to return it to its original position right when it occurs . what i want to do is to allow touch events to occur even outside of the view .

those bugs occur on both the emulator and real devices.

can anyone please help?

---

ok, i've found out the answers:

for 1:

add this line for the listview:

```
this.setCacheColorHint(0);
```

for 2:
add those lines for the listview:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev)
  {
  return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First answer is set in listview in xml as

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Comment: thanks, but i've found the answers in the end. sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: Thanks a lot .u can also use code as u describe above. cool thanks

Comment: Please stop adding "Thanks" to your answers. It only clutters your answer without adding anything of value.